# How to put boxes around quotes in Org mode

Tags: org-mode

I am using Emacs' Org mode to scribble up some notes which all of which are being exported to HTML.

I often need to insert a lot of paragraphs verbatim while citing other research papers. The `#+BEGIN_QUOTE ... #+END_QUOTE` environment is perfect for that.

However, I would also like the quotes to be surrounded by a gray box snapped tight around the quote.

e.g. almost exactly like how the poem Twinkle Twinkle Little Star appears 
below.

> Twinkle, twinkle, little star,
>
> How I wonder what you are!
>
> Up above the world so high,
>
> Like a diamond in the sky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by simply adding the following style to your org file:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style type="text/css"> blockquote {background:#EEEEEE; padding: 3px 13px}</style>
```

You can also put it in a `css` file (e.g. `yourStyle.css`):

```css
blockquote {
    background: #EEEEEE;
    padding: 3px 13px;
}
```

and include it

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <link rel="stylesheet" href="yourStyle.css">
```

*EDIT:* added `type="text/css"` as suggested by user16762

Answer (score 3):

The #+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA answer given by theldoria will work, but it will fail W3C validation because style is missing a type specification. It should strictly be

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style type="text/css"> blockquote {background:#EEEEEE; padding: 3px 13px}</style>
```